# Firestore Cloud to asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have cloud fire-store database which is used for android development, I want to read this data store in fire-store in asp.net MVC? How can I do this?

Comment: Can you supply some code as to what you have tried so far?

Comment: var userId = "12345";
            var currentLoginTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
           var currentUserLogin = new LoginData() { TimestampUtc = currentLoginTime };